# Unable to see the tables inside a docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

Following is the code inside container for the sql:

```
mysql:
    image: mariadb
    command: --max_allowed_packet=32505856
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_USER=abc
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xyz.123
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=abc
    - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    volumes:
    # Using volume mount to mimic prod setup
    - /tmp/mysql:/vol_mount/
```

I have been trying to access the database to view tables but have been unable to do so thus far.

I have tried running commands like:

```
docker exec -it container_name mysql -uabc -p
```

and then have tried bot 'root' and 'xyz.123' when prompted to enter password. But then I get an error like

> "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abc'@'2001:db8:1::a7'
>   (using password: YES)"

I need to know the commands that will allow for me to access the DB and view tables. Thanks.

Comment: check what your volumes do, since the problem is not reproducable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will open your mysql console with user root:

```sh
docker exec -ti mariadb-test sh -c 'mysql -uroot -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
```

Please note that I named the container `mariadb-test` in the compose file you can use a different name if you like.

Similarly you can connect with used `abc`:

```sh
docker exec -ti mariadb-test sh -c 'mysql -uabc -p${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
```

UPDATE:

Run the following to check the environment variables inside your container. They should match the values provided in the docker-compose.yml.

```sh
docker exec -ti mariadb-test sh -c 'env | grep MYSQL'
```

Since in my solution you don't even have to type the password, it should work anyway. Please try to start from a clean state: bring down all the containers, remove volumes and restart the services with this docker-compose file.

Comment: I still am getting the same error after running the command you have suggested. I ran 
docker exec -ti container_name sh -c 'mysql -uroot -proot'

as well as

docker exec -ti tm_sql sh -c 'mysql -uroot -p${root}'

along with trying a host of passwords.

Comment: Then you might have different containers running and you are trying to connect to the wrong one. I will add a command to the post that you can run to verify.

Comment: I ran your updated command and yes, they do match the values provided in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Then stop the container, remove the folder `/tmp/mysql` from host and start it again. The setup works on my machine (so starting from a clean situation).